Maintain active WebSocket connections
I have a test where i connect to websocket and subscribe to updates
my requirements are to subscribe t updates but also maintain 10k active connections per min
i am unable to reach this figure as connections begin to disconnect

I have tried looping and also sending periodic pings using a counter to keep connection alive

tried using flow control action with a pause of 30 sec,,bt still im only able to hit max 10k acitive connections
(I can monitor active connections though dashboard i have provided by devops team)-
is there any way to prevent disconnections and after subscribing keep web socket connections open
(i am using distributed testing with 3 vms)
current set up looks like this
Thread group
|
--transaction controller
  |
   --open connection
   -- connect
   -- subscribe events
   -- loop controller
   |
     -- web socket ping/pong
     --Flow control action


As per documentation:

If you do not close the WebSocket connection yourself, it will stay open at the end of the test.

So it might be the case the connection gets closed from the system under test side, you can enable JMeter debug logging for WebSocket Sampler by adding the next line to log4j2.xml file:
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change. Then inspect jmeter.log file and see who did initiate closing of the WebSocket connection.
